# Questions regarding accounting; can I trust the information?

Tags: accounting, trust

I've noticed a few accounting questions here.  How dependable are the answers I could expect?

Comment: How much can you trust **anything** on the internet?? Answers here are trying to be helpful based upon that user's knowledge. If you don't trust the information... go speak to an accountant yourself.

Comment: This question might be better asked on Freelancing Meta

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [meta]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO.**

If you have a disease I believe you don't go searching in Google and cure yourself based on **strangers' opinions**, but you will go to a doctor and get a checkup and then a therapy if needed.

The same is with accounting information, you won't trust the **opinions** of people from all around the world for your personal accounting. Indeed is almost sure that they won't fit your particular situation.

What you can find here (and elsewhere) are general advices based on personal experiences, but I strongly encourage you to get a professional accountant that will follow and guide you at best for your particular situation and needs.

That will avoid you a lot of troubles.